# Server vs single-player world effects

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Are there any differences with regards to chunk generation or other settings in single-player vs server mode of equivalent versions?

I have a map I'd like to host on a private server for my friend to play with me. However, when I'm on the road without ready internet, I'd like to play it single-player as well.

Will this cause any issues, especially with chunk generation, drops, items, etc (i.e., getting a different chunk generated in server-mode than single-player would have created), or do all server-client version pairs (I'm using 1.6.2) use the same game code?

The main point is that I don't want gameplay to change at all, between single-player and server mode.

Comment: Since... hm, I cant't find the version right away... since some version singleplayer Minecraft actually uses an ad-hoc server running inside the game process. The only difference you'll face between a SP world and local server is pause behavior - when you're on a server, hitting Esc does not pause, so you better gain a habit of catapulting away from the game when you have to linger in a dangerous place.

Comment: I'm actually playing in a locally-hosted MP world with my wife quite often (and it is hosted as 24/7 as I can afford my machine to run). You just have to mind some multiplyer behavior you'll be up against - like your friend being able to log in, revitalize the world around your logged off astral body, and the leave you a world in a different state. Just save in safehouses, and you'll be fine.

Comment: @OrcJMR Safehouses?

Comment: Yes, like, well-lit houses with auto-closing doors. Saving in the middle of a plain in bright day is not safe, as you can not guarantee bright day when you re-enter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no difference in chunk generation as long as the world seed is the same and the Minecraft version number is the same.

The client quite literally uses the server code to handle world generation.

Comment: More correctly, Minecraft singleplayer internally uses a local server.

Comment: @Alvin It's even more local than local—it's internal and not a separate process.